# Adding validation rule(s) depending on option selected from dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validate plugin for the first time. I am in a situation where I have a select box that has three options. I need to do two things:

1. Make the select box required.
2. Depending on the option selected, make other text boxes required.

So...

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value selected></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option Value="3">3</option>
</select>

Coord 1: <input type="text" name="coord1"><br>
Coord 2: <input type="text" name="coord2"><br>
Coord 3: <input type="text" name="coord3"><br>
```

- If option 1 is selected on the dropdown, Coord 1 is required.
- If option 2 is selected, Coords 1 and 2 are required.
- If option 3 is selected, Coord 1 and Coord 3 are required.

How does this work adding custom rules to the validator?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just dynamically add and remove the `required` class. Thats enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 If you need starting itself 

    // $('input[type=text]:eq(0)').prop('required', true);

 $("#selectBox").change(function () {
    var index=this.value-1;
    $('input[type=text]:gt(0)').prop('required', false);
   //  $('input[type=text]:eq(0)').prop('required', true);
    $('input[type=text]:eq('+index+')').prop('required', true);
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/w09ovpkp/5/)

Comment: @mrwienerdog did you check my demo

Comment: Just checking this out.. Thank you so much! Excactly why I love this community so much. Just soaking in exactly what you've done (pretty new to validate).

Comment: @mrwienerdog, answer has nothing in particular to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  It's just toggling the HTML5 `required` property.  You'll have to integrate this into your code.